# Angular DRY Templates

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and I realized that there is a lot of duplicated code in my templates, for example for a single field.

What is the best way to make the templates DRY. I would like to avoid to concatenate strings in some helper functions.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">
        {{'Name'|i18n}}: <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="schema.Name" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="{{'Name'|i18n}}" maxlength="100" required />
    <div ng-show="(submitted || form.Name.$dirty) && form.Name.$invalid">
        <span class="validation-text">{{'Required'|i18n:'i18n.Name'}}</span>
        <span class="validation-arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-hint">{{'NameHint':i18n}}</div>
</div>
```

For example, in ASP.NET MVC there are a lot of helper functions, would be nice to something similar, where I can use e.g.:

```
textBox('schema.Name', { required: true, maxlength')
hint('schema.Name')
```

Comment: What exactly are you after? You wouldn't like to write all that html for a single field? If so you can encapsulate it in a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom directives to reduce the repetition, at the cost of scattering. If really all you need is to include a snippet then the [`include` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) should do the job.

```
<ng-include src="views/foo.html"/>
```

Comment: Your idea with the directives was very nice, works very well.

Comment: yep, can't claim it was my idea though :)